# My jQuery .live() events won't .die()

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery 1.4.3

I have some content that is displayed in a modal window. When the modal opens, I use .live() to attach handlers to several elements. When the modal closes, I use .die() to detach them. However, .die() does not seem to be working because when I reopen the modal, all handlers attached with .live() fire twice. If I close and reopen the modal again, all handlers fire three times, and so on. Why isn't .die() detaching the click events? Code is below:

```
$('.app-action-edit').live('click', function(){

    [some code]

});

$('.app-action-cancel').live('click', function(){

    [some code]

});

$('.app-action-save').live('click', function(){

    [some code]

});

$('.close-modal').click(function(){

    $('.app-action-edit').die('click');
    $('.app-action-cancel').die('click');
    $('.app-action-save').die('click');

    closeModal();

});
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the click handler on '.close-modal' is getting called? Have you put an alert after the die calls to ensure you got past them? It could be that the modal is getting closed another way, bypassing your die code.

Comment: Well this is embarrassing, but you got it. The die() code was never even executing. Can't believe I missed that.

Comment: We've all been there :-)

Comment: Have a similiar problem, although the die() is definately executing

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
function f1 {
   [some code]
}

function f2 {
   [some code]
}

function f3 {
   [some code]
}

$('.app-action-edit').live('click',f1);
$('.app-action-cancel').live('click',f2);
$('.app-action-save').live('click', f3);

$('.close-modal').click(function(){

    $('.app-action-edit').die('click',f1);
    $('.app-action-cancel').die('click',f2);
    $('.app-action-save').die('click',f3);

    closeModal();

});
```

Comment: It doesn't. .live() is still stacking.

Comment: I know your code is an example -- are you 100% sure the selectors are exactly the same.  As the doc page says: "Up to jQuery 1.4.4, in order for .die() to function correctly, the selector used with it must match exactly the selector initially used with .live()."

Comment: @Hogan: Would this include => adding live('click') to a selector. the html found when using that selector is refreshed (html inside div is replaced). Will the die() still work for the new html?

Comment: @AbePetrillo -- It should, as I remember from the source code live events are not stored at the element but instead in the jQuery object where they are checked when needed, the key is the selector, jQuery uses that as a key for the live event data (in this case a dictionary of functions).

Comment: @Hogan: Much appreciated. Like the asker, I found this to eventually be another bug elsewhere. Thanks for the feedback :)